# Function on the real plane that can be expressed in terms of a function on the real line

Tags: functions, solution-verification, contest-math, functional-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)+f(y,z)+f(z,x)=0 \text{ } \forall \text{ } x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}.$ Show that there exists a $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)=g(x)-g(y).$

This was question $A1$ on the $2008$ Putnam. My attempt is given below.

Put in $x=y=z$ to get $3f(x,x)=0.$ This means that $f(x,x)=0$ for all real $x.$ Now, put in $y=z$ to get $$f(x,y)+f(y,y)+f(y,x)=0=f(x,y)+f(y,x).$$ So, $f(x,y)=-f(y,x)$ for all real $x,y.$ In particular, $f(x,0)=-f(0,x).$ Now, let $g(x):=f(x,0).$ This definition makes sense as it's defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and gives out an output that's in $\mathbb{R}.$ Note that $f(x,y)+f(y,0)+f(0,x)=0.$ This gives $f(x,y)=-f(0,x)-f(y,0)=f(x,0)-f(y,0)=g(x)-g(y).$ But, $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary, so this identity holds for all real $x$ and $y,$ as desired.

Is this proof fine? I'm skeptical since my proof seems too simple to be the correct answer to a Putnam question. Another thing that troubles me is that we could've set $g(x):=f(x,a)$ for some real $a$ and gotten the same answer. Does this mean there are infinitely many such $g?$

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine. You can compare yourself with the first results that come up in Approach$0$ if you're uncertain, but your proof is valid and rigorous in my opinion: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x%2Cy)%2Bf(y%2Cz)%2Bf(z%2Cx)%3D0%24&p=1

Comment: There is certainly infinitely many $g(x)$ that work since if $g(x)$ is a solution then $h(x)=g(x)+ a$ is also a solution, since  $g(x)-g(y)=h(x)-h(y)$. It would be interesting to prove that setting $f(x,0)=g(x)+a$ is the same as setting $f(x,a) = g(x)$ or something along those lines, (if it is true) since this would tell you more about the types of $f$ that satisfy this

Comment: @Carlyle, I don't think it is true that setting $f(x,0)=g(x)+a$ is the same as setting $f(x,a)=g(x).$ For example, let $f(x,y)=e^x - e^y.$ Then, we get that $g(x)=e^x - 1 - a$ which is not identically equal to $e^x - e^a.$

Comment: @aqualubix you are correct, that makes it even stranger, since then you have more than "degree of freedom" in creating your $g(x)$.

Comment: @Carlyle The types of $f$ that satisfy this are precisely described by this exercise; they are the functions of the form $f(x,y)=g(x)-g(y)$ for some real function $g$.

Comment: @Servaes you are not wrong of course, but it is possible that there are other descriptions of such functions that give us an intuition of what the graph of such a function might look like for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct and there are infinitely many solutions. A useful resource for this and other Putnam problems is https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/.

Looking at the equation $f(x, y) = g(x) - g(y)$, you can notice that if there is some solution for $g$ than $g + c$ (where $c$ is a constant) is also a solution, since the constants cancel each other out.

Noticing such things is often useful when solving functional equations and is a fairly common "trick". In general you could say something along the lines of: Since, if $h(x)$ is a solution, then $h(x) + c$ is also a solution, we can assume that WLOG $h(0) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, now that you point it out, it seems obvious that there are infinitely many solutions. Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean c=0?

Comment: No. What I meant is $h(0) = 0$. I edited my answer.